# Sonata Admin - why to use admin checkAccess() and not isGranted()

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin

I have a simple project which does not require complicated ACL. Created a custom action in my custom controller that extends `CRUDController`, there I check the access like this:

```
$this->admin->checkAccess('verify', $object);
```

In templates I check access like:

```
{% if admin.isGranted('VERIFY', object) %}
```

My Admin user can have roles: `ADMIN` or `SUPER_ADMIN`.

Wouldn't it be better just to check the role instead:

```
$authorizationChecker->isGranted('SUPER_ADMIN');

{% is_granted('SUPER_ADMIN') %}
```

What's the big deal about using admin for access control? For me just checking if user is `ADMIN` or `SUPER_ADMIN` seems much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you want it to go via the 'admin' and not straight to the AuthorizationChecker is the following:

Sonata will take into account its settings, as you can change the security strategy used by sonata (noop, vs roles, vs acl, vs custom), without having to make changes to where you 'check' access.

does this explanation make sense?